# How to test main.dart

Tags: testing, flutter, dart

main.dart

```
int sumInt(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
int main(List<String> args) {
  var result;
  var a = 10;

  result = sumInt(a, 50);
  return result;
}
```

gao.dart

```
int calculate() {
  return 6 +10;
}
```

gao_test.dart

```
import 'package:gao/gao.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test("test to check add method", () {
    expect(calculate, result );
  });
}
```

The question is, how do I test main.dart? I think importing main.dart in gao_test.dart, but there was an error importing. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to import it with a prefix in order to be able to reference the `main` function (otherwise it is shadowed by your tests main function), so something like this (depending on where main.dart lives):

```dart
import 'package:gao/main.dart' as gao_main;
import 'package:test/test.dart';

main() {
  test('main', () {
    expect(gao_main.main([]), 60); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. You can use annotation @visibleForTesting to mark anything that will be available for testing. But since test class also has a main, you can't import the "other main" to it.

Comment: Okay.I get it. Thanks dude

Comment: Mà anh ơi.Ví dụ em muốn test coverage cho bài tập dart của em thì em dùng CodeCOV nhưng nó lại không hỗ trợ cho Dart 2, h phải làm sao anh nhỉ.Tiến xa hơn nữa em là test coverage cho Flutter thì phải làm sao anh.Anh có thể chỉ em cụ thể được không